# Vote functionality issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, voting-system

Please bear with me as I am having difficulty phrasing this question.

I am trying to learn and implement a vote functionality in a rails app, I am using the [activerecord-reputation-system](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system) gem.

I have successfully been able to implement this functionality in my a users show view the issue I have is in my micropost feed.

when a user is signed in he/she is re-directed to the home page which now has a micropost feed this is where I want to put the voting links but it just isn't working.

Do I have to define voting routes for the home page controller? like I did for the micropost

```
resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy] do
  member { post :vote}
end
```

or what??

routes are included in original post, plan on using post method. this is what i have for my links:

```
<% if current_user?(micropost.user) && !current_user.voted_for?(micropost) %>
 | <%= link_to "up", vote_micropost_path(micropost, type: "up"), method: "post" %>
  | <%= link_to "down", vote_micropost_path(micropost, type: "down"), method: "post" %>
    <%= link_to "Delete", micropost, method: :delete,
                                     data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
                                     title: micropost.quote %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: What kind of links are you planning to have, and what HTTP method (GET? POST?) do you want them to use? Can you edit with all the relevant routes you have right now?

Comment: edited question to show relevant info

Answer (score 1):

Check this great [Active Record Reputation System](http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system) railscast.

[ryanb](https://github.com/ryanb) goes through **activerecord-reputation-system** gem and builds from scratch solution.

Comment: I did use this resource, the issue i am having is the placement of the links. It works fine if it is on a user show page but thats not where i want it. Thank you though